# What is the effective query to retrieve related information from related MySQL tables, when there can be search in both tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables like below, and I use php to run my queries;

table_a

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| taf1   | taf2   | taf3   | taf4   |
+========+========+========+========+
| dataa1 | dataa2 | dataa3 | dataa4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| datab1 | datab2 | datab3 | datab4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| datac1 | datac2 | datac3 | datac4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| datad1 | datad2 | datad3 | datad4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

table_b

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| tbf1   | tbf2   | tbf3   | tbf4   |
+========+========+========+========+
| dataa5 | dataa6 | dataa7 | dataa4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| datab5 | datab6 | datab7 | datab4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| datac5 | datac6 | datac7 | datac4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| datad5 | datad6 | datad7 | datad4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

`taf1`, `taf2`, `taf3`, and `taf4` are fields of first table, and `tbf1`, `tbf2`, `tbf3`, and `tbf4` are fields of second table. `taf4` and `tbf4` have same entries, to link between the two tables. In the results page, I display `taf1`, `taf2`, `taf3` and `tbf1` fields. Also, search can be made in these 4 fields (a dropdown is given so that user can select search field). How can I do this?

Currently, I use the following code;

```
$key = "keyword";
$field = "fieldname";

if($field == "tbf1"){
  $engine = "table_b";
  //search in table_b. code incomplete.
}else{

  $query = "SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE $field LIKE '%$key%'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $link = $row['taf4'];
    $query2 = "SELECT NUMBER FROM table_b WHERE tbf4 = '$link'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    echo $row['taf1']." - ".$row['taf2']." - ".$row['taf3']." - ".$row2['tbf1']."<br />";
  }

}
```

Is there any simple and effective method to do this?

Comment: @MarkBaker could you post the code..

Comment: This is something you really need to learn - http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @MarkBaker ok ok :) i agree that i really need to learn it. but can you post a code to solve my current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT taf.*,
       tbf.*
  FROM table_a taf
 INNER JOIN table_b tbf
         ON tbf.tbf4 = taf.taf4
 WHERE taf......
```

Comment: what is `taf` and `tbf` ?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ It's a table alias, another name for the table.

Comment: `taf` and `tab` are aliases for `table_a` and `table_b`... I always have a tendency to use aliases when I use joins, because there are occasions when you need to join against the same table multiple times, and then the alias is unique identifier